# How to Pass Todays/Current date from Fitnesse Table Cell to C# fixture

Tags: c#-4.0, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I want to pass `!today (yyyy/MM/dd)` from fitnesse table cell to C# fixture. It's not working. However, if I use it on wiki, it's working fine.

Working:

`!define !today`

Not working:

`!|classname|`

`|!today (yyyy/MM/dd)|`

where I am going wrong.
Need help in how to pass today's date from fitnesse table to C# fixture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading `!` in a table means the contents of the table are interpreted literally, so symbols like `!today` are not expanded.  Use a plain table:

```
|classname|
|!today (yyyy/MM/dd)|
```

Comment: If I remove ! before classname on fitnesses table, how would it be able to communicate with C# fixture. How will fitnesse know that it's a class?

Comment: FitNesse will check for a class name, with or without the !

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. It worked. But is there any way to pass symbols inside a table cell (table leading with "!") and still retrieving symbol's value in the table cell?

Comment: No, in a table prefixed with !, no symbol values are retrieved.